# Running parallel CUDA tasks

Tags: cuda, gpu

I am about to create GPU-enabled program using CUDA technology. It is supposed to be C# Emgu or C++ Cuda toolkit (not yet decided).

I need to use all GPU power (I have card with 16 GPU cores). How do I run 16 tasks in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of. 16 GPU cores is, on pre 6xx series, equal to 16*8=128 cores. On 6xx series it is 16*32=512 cores. That does not mean you should limit yourself to 128/512 tasks.

Second: emgu seems to be a OpenCV wrapper for .NET, and is related to image processing. It generally has nothing to do with GPU programming. Might be some algorithms have been gpu accelerated, but I don't know anything about that. The alternative to CUDA in this is OpenCL, not OpenCV. If you will be using CUDA technology like you say, you have no alternative to CUDA, as only CUDA is CUDA.

When it comes to starting tasks, you only tell the GPU how many threads you wish to run. Actually, you tell the GPU how many blocks, and how many threads pr. block you wish to run. This is done when you call the cuda function itself. You don't want to limit yourself to 128/512 threads either, but experiment.

Don't know your knowledge on GPGPU programming, but remember that you can not run tasks as you do on the CPU. You can not run 128 different tasks, all threads have to run the exact same instructions (except for when branching, which should generally be avoided).

Comment: A little clarification: I was meaning OpenCV, not OpenCL, as my main area is indeed image processing (the same reason for considering Emgu). For the rest of your reply - thank you very much!

Comment: Ok. Then saying you want it CUDA accelerated is kind of confusing. CUDA is quite suitable for this kind of processing, but my guess is that OpenCV is, if it's GPU accelerated, using OpenCL as this is cross vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you want sufficient threads to fill all the streaming multiprocessors. At a minimum that is `.25 * MULTIPROCESSORS * MAX_THREADS_PER_MULTIPROCESSOR`.

Specifically in CUDA now, suppose you have some CUDA kernel `__global__ void square_array(float *a, int N)`...

Now when you launch the kernel you specify the number of blocks and the number of threads per block

```
square_array <<< n_blocks, n_threads_per_block >>> (a, N);
```

Note: you need to get more framiliar with the CUDA parallel programming model as you not approaching to in a manor which will use all your GPU power.  Consider reading [Programming Massively Parallel Processors, A Hands-on Approach](http://www.elsevierdirect.com/morgan_kaufmann/Excerpt_Parallel_Processors.pdf).

Comment: Please change the first paragraph to be sufficient threads to fill all the streaming multiprocessors. At a minimum that is  25% x MULTIPROCESSORS x MAX_THREADS_PER_MULTIPROCESSOR. CUDA cores should not be in the answer.

Comment: @GregSmith do you have a source I can reference?

Comment: "CUDA C Programming Guide" sections 5.2 discusses application, device, and multiprocessor level parallelism. Three webinars that are extremely useful are (1) "CUDA Warps and Occupancy" at http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/cuda_webinars_WarpsAndOccupancy.pdf (2) "GPU Performance Analysis and Optimization" at http://developer.download.nvidia.com/GTC/PDF/GTC2012/PresentationPDF/S0514-GTC2012-GPU-Performance-Analysis.pdf. (3) "CUDA C/C++ Streams and Concurrency" at http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf